# Small android app that gives a movie based on the chosen genre

Tags: c#, android, form, asp.net-web-api, xamarin

Working on my first "big" project using the mighty Xamarin. Likewise my first venture in XAML so I suppose most focus will be going towards these new areas. Performance- and user-experience related remarks are welcome as well though. Or you know, just any issue you can see.

The solution consists of 3 actively used projects (the 4th - MoviePicker.Android - doesn't contain any platform-specific code). There's the shared Xamarin.Forms project, a ASP.NET Web Api 2 project and a PCL to share models between the API and the app. I will omit the PCL since it's just a few models with JSON annotations.

## Web API

### WebApiConfig

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "test",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional}
        );
    }
}
```

### BaseController

```
public class BaseController : ApiController
{
    protected const string ApiKey = "Will_Move_To_AppSettings";
    protected TMDbClient Client = new TMDbClient(ApiKey);
}
```

### MovieController

```
namespace MoviePickerApi.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/movies")]
    public class MovieController : BaseController
    {
        public MovieController()
        {
            Client.GetConfig();
        }

        [Route("~/api/genres")]
        [HttpGet]
        [ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<Genre>))]
        public IHttpActionResult GetGenres()
        {
            return Ok(Client.GetGenres());
        }

        [Route("~/api/genres/{id:int}")]
        [HttpGet]
        [ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<MovieResult>))]
        public IHttpActionResult GetMoviesForGenre(int id)
        {
            var results = Client.GetGenreMovies(id).Results;

            foreach (var genre in results)
            {
                genre.PosterPath = Client.GetImageUrl("original", genre.PosterPath).ToString();
            }
            return Ok(results);
        }

        [Route("{id:int}")]
        [HttpGet]
        [ResponseType(typeof(Movie))]
        public IHttpActionResult GetMovieDetails(int id)
        {
            var movie = Client.GetMovie(id);
            movie.PosterPath = Client.GetImageUrl("original", movie.PosterPath).ToString();
            return Ok(movie);
        }
    }
}
```

### UserController

```
namespace MoviePickerApi.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/users")]
    public class UserController : BaseController
    {
        private readonly MoviePickerContext _db = new MoviePickerContext();

        [Route("{id:int}")]
        [HttpGet]
        [ResponseType(typeof(User))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetUser(int? id)
        {
            var user = await _db.Users.FindAsync(id);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(user);
        }

        [Route("create")]
        [HttpPost]
        [ResponseType(typeof(User))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CreateUser([FromBody] User user)
        {
            if (UserExists(user.Email))
            {
                return Conflict();
            }

            _db.Users.Add(user);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

            user.Password = string.Empty;
            return Ok(user);
        }

        [Route("login")]
        [HttpPost]
        [ResponseType(typeof(User))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Login([FromBody] User user)
        {
            var dbUser = await _db.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Email == user.Email);
            if (dbUser == null || dbUser.Password != user.Password)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(dbUser);
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private bool UserExists(string email)
        {
            return _db.Users.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Email == email) != null;
        }
    }
}
```

## Xamarin.Forms

### DataSource

```
public class DataSource
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    private const string BaseUrl = "http://mpdev.azurewebsites.net/api";

    public DataSource()
    {
        _client = new HttpClient();
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Genre>> GetGenresAsync()
    {
        var data = await _client.GetStringAsync(BaseUrl + "/genres");
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Genre>>(data);
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<MovieSearchResult>> GetMoviesForGenreAsync(int genreId)
    {
        var data = await _client.GetStringAsync(BaseUrl + "/genres/" + genreId);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MovieSearchResult>>(data);
    }

    public async Task<Movie> GetMovieAsync(int movieId)
    {
        var data = await _client.GetStringAsync(BaseUrl + "/movies/" + movieId);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie>(data); 
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> RegisterAsync(string email, string password, string firstname, string lastname)
    {
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("email", email),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("firstname", firstname),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("lastname", lastname),
                });

        return await _client.PostAsync(BaseUrl + "/users/create", content);
    }
}
```

### Session

```
public class Session
{ 
    public User User { get; set; }

    private readonly DataSource _dataSource = new DataSource();
    public DataSource DataSource
    {
        get { return _dataSource; }
    }

    public string DatabasePath
    {
        get { return Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "database.db3"); }
    }

    public bool IsLoggedIn
    {
        get { return User != null; }
    }
}
```

### App

```
public class App
{
    public static Page GetMainPage()
    {
        var session = new Session();
        return new NavigationPage(new WelcomePage(session));
    }
}
```

### WelcomePage

```
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <Label Text="Welcome!" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Font="Bold, Small" />
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <Button Text="Login" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" Clicked="OnLoginButtonClicked" />
            <Button Text="Register" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" Clicked="OnRegisterButtonClicked" />
        </StackLayout>
        <ActivityIndicator x:Name="_activityIndicator" Color="Aqua" IsRunning="false" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>

public partial class WelcomePage : ContentPage
{   
    private readonly Session _session;

    public WelcomePage(Session session)
    {
        _session = session;
        InitializeComponent ();
    }

    private async void OnLoginButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _activityIndicator.IsRunning = true;
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new LoginPage(_session));
        _activityIndicator.IsRunning = false;
    }

    private async void OnRegisterButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _activityIndicator.IsRunning = true;
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new RegistrationPage(_session));
        _activityIndicator.IsRunning = false;
    }
}
```

### LoginPage

```
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <!--- Menu -->
        <Label Text="Welcome!" HorizontalOptions="Center" Font="Bold, 30" />
        <Entry x:Name="_emailEntry" Keyboard="Email" Placeholder="Enter your email address" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <Entry x:Name="_passwordEntry" Keyboard="Text" Placeholder="Enter your password" IsPassword="true" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <Button Text="Log me in" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" Clicked="OnLoginButtonClicked" />

        <ActivityIndicator x:Name="_activityIndicator" Color="Aqua" IsRunning="false" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>   

public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
{   
    private readonly Session _session;

    public LoginPage(Session session)
    {
        _session = session;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void OnLoginButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        _activityIndicator.IsRunning = true;
        var isValidTask = IsValidLogin();
        var isValid = await isValidTask;

        if (isValid)
        {
            var genres = await _session.DataSource.GetGenresAsync();
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new GenrePage(_session, genres));
        }
        else
        {
            var alert = new AlertConfig
            {
                Message = "The entered credentials are invalid",
                Title = "Invalid login",
                OkText = "Okay then.."
            };
            var dialogService = new UserDialogService();
            await dialogService.AlertAsync(alert);
        }

        if (isValidTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            _activityIndicator.IsRunning = false;
        }
    }

    private async Task<bool> IsValidLogin()
    {
        var email = _emailEntry.Text;
        var password = _passwordEntry.Text;

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("email", email),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password)
                });

            HttpResponseMessage response;
            try
            {
                response = await client.PostAsync("http://mpdev.azurewebsites.net/api/users/login", content);

                var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(json);
                _session.User = obj;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //TODO: log
                var alert = new AlertConfig
                {
                    Message = "Something went wrong with your request, try again later.",
                    Title = "Uh oh",
                    OkText = "Fk dis app"
                };
                var dialogService = new UserDialogService();
                dialogService.AlertAsync(alert);

                return false;
            }

            return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
        }
    }
}
```

### RegistrationPage

```
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <Label Text="Registration" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Font="Bold, Small" />
        <Entry x:Name="_email" Keyboard="Email" Placeholder="Enter your email address" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <Entry x:Name="_password" Keyboard="Text" Placeholder="Enter your password" IsPassword="true" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <Entry x:Name="_firstname" Keyboard="Text" Placeholder="Enter your first name" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <Entry x:Name="_lastname" Keyboard="Text" Placeholder="Enter your last name" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <Button Text="Register me" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" Clicked="OnRegistrationButtonClicked" />
        <ActivityIndicator x:Name="_activityIndicator" Color="Aqua" IsRunning="false" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>

public partial class RegistrationPage : ContentPage
{   
    private readonly Session _session;

    public RegistrationPage (Session session)
    {
        _session = session;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void OnRegistrationButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _activityIndicator.IsRunning = true;

        var response = await _session.DataSource.RegisterAsync(_email.Text, _password.Text, _firstname.Text, _lastname.Text);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(json);
            _session.User = obj;

            var genres = await _session.DataSource.GetGenresAsync();
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new GenrePage(_session, genres));
        }
        else
        {
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Conflict)
            {
                var alert = await DisplayAlert("User exists",
                    "A user with this email address already exists",
                    "Go to login",
                    "Cancel");

                // User clicked on "Go to login"
                if (alert)
                {
                    await Navigation.PushAsync(new LoginPage(_session));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var alert = new AlertConfig
                {
                    Message = "Something went wrong with your request, try again later.",
                    Title = "Uh oh",
                    OkText = "Fk dis app"
                };
                new UserDialogService().AlertAsync(alert);
            }
        }

        _activityIndicator.IsRunning = false;  
    }
}
```

### GenrePage

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
    <Label Text="Select a genre" Font="30" HorizontalOptions="Center" />

    <TableView Intent="Menu">
        <TableRoot>
            <TableSection x:Name="_genreCells">
                <!-- Fill with custom cells in code -->
            </TableSection>
        </TableRoot>
    </TableView>
</StackLayout>

public partial class GenrePage : ContentPage
{   
    private readonly IEnumerable<Genre> _genres; 
    private readonly Session _session;

    public GenrePage(Session session, IEnumerable<Genre> genres)
    {
        _session = session;
        _genres = genres;
        InitializeComponent ();

        foreach (var genre in _genres) 
        {
            _genreCells.Add(new GenreCell(genre, _session, Navigation));
        }
    }
}

public class GenreCell : TextCell
{
    private readonly Session _session;
    private readonly INavigation _navigation;
    public Genre Genre { get; set; }

    public GenreCell(Genre genre, Session session, INavigation navigation)
    {
        Genre = genre;
        _session = session;
        _navigation = navigation;
        Text = genre.Name;
        Tapped += TappedInternal;
    }

    private async void TappedInternal(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var movie = (await _session.DataSource.GetMoviesForGenreAsync(Genre.Id)).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
        var movieDetails = await _session.DataSource.GetMovieAsync(movie.Id);
        await _navigation.PushAsync(new MoviePage(movieDetails));
    }
}
```

### MoviePage

```
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Label x:Name="_title" Font="Bold, 30" />
        <Image x:Name="_image" WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="250" />
        <Label x:Name="_description" Font="15" />

        <Button Text="More information" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Clicked="OnMoreInformationClicked" />
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" >
            <Button Text="Decline" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Clicked="OnDeclineClicked" />
            <Button Text="Maybe later" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Clicked="OnMaybeClicked" />
            <Button Text="Watched!" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Clicked="OnWatchedClicked" />
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>

public partial class MoviePage : ContentPage
{   
    private readonly Movie _movie;

    public MoviePage (Movie movie)
    {
        _movie = movie;
        InitializeComponent();

        _title.Text = string.Format ("{0}({1})", _movie.Title, _movie.ReleaseDate.HasValue ? _movie.ReleaseDate.Value.Year.ToString () : "Unknown");
        _image.Source = new UriImageSource {
            CachingEnabled = true,
            CacheValidity = new TimeSpan(5, 0, 0, 0),
            Uri = new Uri(_movie.PosterPath)
        };
        _description.Text = _movie.Overview;

        // Main layout: Padding = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0)
    }

    private void OnMoreInformationClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
    private void OnDeclineClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
    private void OnMaybeClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
    private void OnWatchedClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but when this app will be done, how will I be able to find it on the market? ;)

Comment: I'll probably rent a few big billboards in my hometown so if you ever pass through there, you'll see it! Or, well, I'll announce it in [the CodeReview chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor).

Comment: `if (dbUser == null || dbUser.Password != user.Password)` -- are you storing your passwords in the clear?

Comment: @mjolka: yes. If it helps, I left a `//TODO: encrypt` note somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

I'm just going to comment on one line:

> ```
> if (dbUser == null || dbUser.Password != user.Password)
> ```

As you confirmed, you're currently storing passwords in the clear. Encrypting passwords is not the right solution either.

[Cryptographic Right Answers](http://www.daemonology.net/blog/2009-06-11-cryptographic-right-answers.html) (2009, Colin Percival, author of scrypt)

> **Password handling: As soon as you receive a password, hash it using
>   [scrypt](http://www.tarsnap.com/scrypt/) or [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) and erase the plaintext password from memory.**
>
> Do NOT
>   store users' passwords. Do NOT hash them with MD5. Use a real key
>   derivation algorithm. PBKDF2 is the most official standard; but scrypt
>   is stronger.  Please keep in mind that even if YOUR application isn't
>   particularly sensitive, your users are probably re-using passwords
>   which they have used on other, more sensitive, websites -- so if you
>   screw up how you store your users' passwords, you might end up doing
>   them a lot of harm.

[How To Safely Store A Password](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/) (2010)

> **Use bcrypt**
>
> Use bcrypt. Use bcrypt. Use bcrypt. Use bcrypt. Use bcrypt.
>   Use bcrypt. Use bcrypt. Use bcrypt. Use bcrypt.

[How to securely hash passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/31846) (2013)

> **Conclusion**
>
> Use bcrypt. PBKDF2 is not bad either. If you use scrypt you will be a
>   "slightly early adopter" with the risks that are implied by this
>   expression; but it would be a good move for scientific progress
>   ("crash dummy" is a very honourable profession).